# Smart random generated 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, 2d

Hey so I am looking to generate a smart random 2D array. What do I mean? Well smart random number generation is when you generate numbers that are not non-repeating, but does not repeat soon after being generated.

This technique is pretty available and is often used in for example, generating random music playlists. However, what I am looking for is to have it in 2D. So not only do numbers not randomly cluster in each row, but across each column and diagonal as well. Can this actually be done?

Comment: so you want to generate a 2d array right ?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just generate a  non repeating set of numbers, shuffle it and repeat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given position you could determine all its neighbours:

```
  function neighbours(arr, x, y, value){
    const result = [];
    for(const [dx,dy] of [[1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [-1, -1], [-1,0], [-1, 1]])
      if(arr[x + dx] && (y + dy) in arr[x + dx])
         result.push(arr[x + dx][y + dy]);
   return result;
 }
```

Now when generating the 2D array, we could choose values randomly, excluding all direct neighbours:

```
 const random = arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

 const set = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => i);

 const result = [];
 for(let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  result[x] = [];
  for(let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
     const exclude = neighbours(result, x, y);
     result[x][y] = random(set.filter(el => !exclude.includes(el)));
  }
}
```

Now the numbers wont repeat as direct neighbours. You could extend that to *neighbours neighbours* and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want is not clear, but a simple approach is

1. generate a random valid even if ugly 2d array
2. establish a "score" function that given an array returns higher values for better ones
3. apply small a random mutation that keeps the solution valid if it increases the score
4. repeat 3 until satisfied or time runs out

This can be refined a lot (e.g. having a score function that supports incremental computation, using a pool of best runners instead of a single one, adding a cooling temperature etc...) but for small cases even the plain simple approach may be enough.

Of course if the score function has a particular form may be a dynamic programming solution can find the optimal best quickly... but for that you need to be a lot more precise about what you are looking for exactly.